# (Gnuplot ) How to create a .png image with no spaces between graph and image edges?

Tags: gnuplot

I'm currently trying to output an image in Gnuplot that only shows the plot, without tics, border, or margin. I'm using "splot", and the commands

```
set terminal pngcairo size 1024,768 enhanced
set output 'output.png'
unset colorbox
set lmargin 0
set rmargin 0
set tmargin 0
set bmargin 0
unset tics
set pm3d map
set palette
set zero 1E-40
set cbrange[0:16]
set xrange[-1.7999999105699706625216549582546577:-1.7999999105620294592711161385523155]
set yrange[-2.941176470588235211202093999389572e-12:2.941176470588235211202093999389572e-12]
splot "splot.dat" using 1:2:3 with pm3d notitle
unset output
```

But the image I obtain is [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oJae.png). The margin is white so it gets blended with the background of this web page but if you save the image and view it, one can clearly see that the margin exists. I would really appreciate any help with this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the margins relative to the screen like this:

```
set lmargin screen 0
set rmargin screen 1
set tmargin screen 0
set bmargin screen 1
```

Without the `screen` keyword the coordinates are interpreted relative to the graph area.

Nice picture btw.